# Applying kinetic energy operator to wavefunction question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

I am using the book Universty physics volume 3 by openstax from Samuel Ling. Below I uploaded a picture, when applying the kinetic energy operator to the sin part since that is the only part that has an "x" in it. At the red arrow, they have h bar squared, but after applying the second derivatie of the sin they have h squared at the green arrow. the first derivative of the sin is cosine, and then the derivative of that is the minus sin. So the minus in from the h bar squared disappers, and then by the chain rule you get Pi^2/L^2. But h bar squared is h squared divided by 4pi^2, the pi^2 squared cancels out by the pi^2/L^2 but you still have h/4. so shouldnt it be 8mL^2 in the denominator(instead of 2mL^2 as here?). I am off by a factor 1/4 for some reason and dont know why. [image]

Comment: Yeah, it looks his hbar is h/pi.

Comment: but hbar is h/2pi right? so this is a mistake?

Comment: Yes, that would be the only conclusion. Maybe he has a different definition... Which would be silly. You are just right!